# how to let bash read the "pressed key" at press time not after hitting ENTER

Tags: bash

according to my limited knowlege i'm not sure if i wrote the right title for this question.
anyhow i want to know how to the bash detect the pressed key and do something according to the script structure ,
until now i know the `read somthing ; do_somthing_to $something`
i want a script similar to the folowing :

```
#!/bin/bash
while read a
  do
    echo "$a pressed"
  done
```

but i wanted it to give me the results at press time (it shouldn't wait me to hit enter)!

and thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify the number of characters to read with `-n`. So, in your case:

```
#! /bin/bash
read -n1 a
echo "$a pressed"
```

You might need to include `-s` to avoid printing the key when pressed.

Comment: thanks a lot , but it shows me the key doubled as "aa pressed" , does it have a solution or i should deal with it like that ?

Comment: @younes: Have you read the last line?

Comment: oh okay :D ! thanks a lot brother :3